# document.ready() function slowing my UIs performance

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-events

I have a UI page in my application which is taking to much time to load.

In the HTML source, as you can see, I have a series of **.click()** jQuery event handlers in the `document.ready()` function as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {
$("#selectAllCountry").click( function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr('rel') + " INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
    return false;
});


... and many more...
```

Does it affect my page's performance? Does moving this .click handler in the HTML body will help improve it?

One more thing, I am using **iframe** to load another page in the same domain. But, even if I remove the iframe tag, the performance improvement to is not much. I know, this iframe thing is a major bottleneck in the performance of my application and I will eventually remove it, but there is still something else I need to do for this page. What that particular thing might be?

My page is slow slow in performance, even  Chrome hung when I tried to get the source in order to reproduce the scenario in jsbin.

Comment: What have you observed, performance-wise?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are getting downvotes due to the wall of code you posted. Consider the first S in SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). For the record, I did not downvote.

Comment: Do you actually like the sort of code duplication that we are seeing here? Shouldn't the first question be: How can I reduce this...ceremonial incantation to something manageable?

Comment: ya...@flq...I know...This thing I have done in hurry...and it is something I shouldn't have done. I have now edited the question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could cut down the number of click handlers to 1 as they all seem to do the same thing.

If you can put classes of `select` and `deselect` on the elements you can just do this:

```
 $(".select, .deselect").click( function() {
    var t = $(this);
    $("#" + t.attr('rel') + " input:checkbox")
        .attr('checked', t.hasClass('select'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You are making it too easy for this guy.